# Error in using KSoap in android?

Tags: android

I am using the following code to call webservice.I very new to using Ksoap in android.I have managed to call 1 webservice and parse the data.However when i use the same (I have changed the parameters soapaction,namespace...)to parse another webservice i get the following error.The parameters that i have set the Soapaction,namespace..are all set correctly.
i have made a method that calls the webservice;

```
public void showdetails()
    {

        String result = "";
        SoapObject resultRequestSOAP = null;
        SoapObject resultRequestSOAPbody =null;

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE_Transaction, METHOD_NAME_Transaction);

        request.addProperty("TransactionType","payment");
        request.addProperty("MerchantId","543");
        request.addProperty("amount","0.02");
        request.addProperty("CCNo","4111111111111111");
        request.addProperty("CCExpMonth","11");
        request.addProperty("CCExpYear","22");
        request.addProperty("Source","aa");
        request.addProperty("profileId","788");
        //request.addProperty("ClientIPAddress","120.138.99.2");
       //request.addProperty("GEOCode","0.000000,0.000000");

            //Some more fields that are not mandatory


        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL_Transaction);
        androidHttpTransport.debug = true;

        try
        {
            androidHttpTransport.setXmlVersionTag("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding= \"UTF-8\"?>");
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION_Transaction, envelope);
            String requestDumpString = androidHttpTransport.requestDump;
            System.out.println("requestDump : " + requestDumpString);

            resultRequestSOAP = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
            //  resultRequestSOAP = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse(); // Output received
            result = resultRequestSOAP.toString(); // Result string
            System.out.println("OUTPUT : " + result);


            if (envelope.bodyIn instanceof SoapFault) 
            {
                String str= ((SoapFault) envelope.bodyIn).faultstring;
                Log.i("TAG", str);
            } else {
                SoapObject resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
                Log.d("WS", String.valueOf(resultsRequestSOAP));
            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

I get the issue in the following statement:

```
resultRequestSOAP = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
```

The error is as follows:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.ksoap2.SoapFault cannot be cast to org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject
```

Can somebody please help me in this issue.I have searched a lot but havent been able to resolve it.When i call other webservice it returns me the envelope.bodyIn.

Comment: SoapFault means your envelope.bodyIn is the description of an error.

Comment: I too know the error is at that line when i try to do resultRequestSOAP.toString i get the following error SoapFault - faultcode: 'soap:Server' faultstring: 'System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.Can u please tell me what change do i need to make ?

Comment: can u check what kind of request parameters your server is expecting

Comment: is your server expecting request in xml tags. request embeded in xml tags?? Check in what form your request should be. May be that will help you get rid of this problem

Answer (score -1):

i edited your code as please try like this

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE_Transaction,
            METHOD_NAME_Transaction); // set up request
    request.addProperty("TransactionType","payment");
    request.addProperty("MerchantId","543");
    request.addProperty("amount","0.02");
    request.addProperty("CCNo","4111111111111111");
    request.addProperty("CCExpMonth","11");
    request.addProperty("CCExpYear","22");
    request.addProperty("Source","aa");
    request.addProperty("profileId","788");
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
            SoapEnvelope.VER11); // put all required data into a soap
    // envelope
    // envelope.dotNet = true; This is needed else gives error - 42,
    // parameter is not recognised!!
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request); // prepare request
    AndroidHttpTransport httpTransport = new AndroidHttpTransport(
            URL_Transaction);
    httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION_Transaction, envelope);

    SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
      System.out.println(result.toString());
```

Comment: Still the same error @Amit.

Comment: Got the error.The actual problem was i had not pass all the parameters.Other fields were mandatory to pass in android code.Though if not entered in the browser it called the webservice.Thanks all.

Comment: i told you to check the request parameters and you had asked the same question yesterday posting it as a different question